# How to pack addons into blend file?

Tags: add-on, packed-data

I am using assets and scatter function of botaniq addon and I would like to upload this to a render farm online - which allows me to upload folders as well.

I tried pack all resources which did not pack botaniq files however.

So how would I pack all assets from botaniq into a single file or folder so I can upload to the online render farm?

Comment: Hello, you can't pack addons into a blend file. You'll have to see directly with your render farm how they handle addons.

Comment: There is a way to include the add-on inside the blend file, which is called "bundling" the add-on. The process of bundling an add-on is a bit more complex and it involves adding the add-on python script and any other necessary files within the blend file and then using a special script that will register the add-on automatically when the blend file is opened. This way you can share the blend file without the need to share the add-on separately. But unfortunately I don't know the specifics to this method...

Comment: You should pack the assets generated by the add-on, not the add-on itself. Most render farms do not allow running code on their computers and that's for a good reason - it's not safe. Ask them for help, maybe they support it, but it makes absolutely no sense to include 5GB add-on with your file when sending to render. That's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to collect all the .zip files of the addons you are trying to install.

Then, upload these to your render farm.

Create a python script to install these, like this:

```py
import bpy

// Install it
bpy.ops.preferences.addon_install(overwrite=True,filepath="addon.zip")
// Enable
bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module="addon_name")
```

Repeat this for every single addon. Then you can also enable settings for each addon using python. Enable blender tooltips to see the actual python properties.

Addon docs: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.preferences.html#bpy.ops.preferences

Enable python tooltips: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/help.html

Answer (score 1):

Select all linked collections (all botaniq assets) and make them local by going into *Objects > Relations > Make Local > All*

Then you use *Pack Resources* to pack all your assets into the blend file as usual.